# Layout do modem, é possível alterar?

Tags: html, css

Ao entrar na pagina de configuração do meu modem `192.168.0.1` tenho o seguinte layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de reformular esta página, mas não sei se é possível, fiz buscas na internet e não encontrei nada específico. Se **sim** o que devo fazer?

Comment: Deve ser possivel obter o firmware e fazer "engenharia reversa" (dependendo pode ser até simples) para modificar nele, mas não creio que seja escopo do site. Fora que depende muito do equipamento.

Comment: Provavelmente não dá. A menos que você substitua o firmware original do equipamento por um firmware customizado seu (e isso vai além do front-end de admin).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, eu re-li o tópico de ajuda, então estou dentro das informações aqui passadas, não quero ser banido por uma pergunta que outras pessoas podem se interessar.

Comment: De onde vem essa página? Que equipamento você está acessando? Foi você que desenvolveu? Conhece quem desenvolveu? Você tem acesso ao firmware? Você consegue reprogramar o hardware? Você é permitido fazer isso?  No tópico de como perguntar diz que você precisa ser específico, então dê detalhes.

Comment: @bfavaretto está certo. No caso os arquivos dessa página é dó próprio modem, correto? ou seja esta dentro dele?

Comment: Guilherme, para qual link você é direcionado ao clicar em **OPEN SOURCE SOFTWARE INFORMATION**?

Comment: Isso não é motivo de banimento, vc não esta entendendo o proposito do site, fechar uma pergunta OFF não é o mesmo que te castigar com 80 chibatadas, apenas indica que o assunto é **fora de escopo** e não faz parte do site e sera fechada, não tem haver contigo, apenas com o assunto.

Comment: @Randrade, `http://192.168.0.1/OSSattribution.asp` para este, vou ler, **GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 2, June 1991**, No caso não da mesmo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, entendi, agora estou esperto pra fazer perguntas.

Comment: Sim, o modem tem um web server interno servindo a interface de administração. Isso fica gravado numa memória interna do equipamento.

Comment: Errar é normal, eu erro todos os dias, o que importa é entender no que erramos e saber receber bem as criticas, claro que não deve tolerar grosserias :) Boa sorte.

Comment: @bfavaretto, entendi agora, obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves acho que entendi, vc confundiu bloqueio no site com banimento, são coisas diferentes, veja: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5952/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, opa, valeu, tá, a pergunta foi respondia nos comentários, neste caso, eu deleto ou deixo aberto?

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves eu não sei, o pessoal tá discutindo no chat a respeito, não sei o que falar, ando meio por fora das coisas, quem sabe dá pra salvar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento está bem.

Comment: Eu achei interessante a pergunta.

Comment: @Renan ser interessante e estar no escopo são coisas bem diferentes.

Comment: Tenho colegas da faculdade que no TCC deles, eles alteraram o firmware de um modem para atender a certo proposito

Comment: @MarceloBoni porém, não sei como funciona o firmware nunca mexi com isto.